# SQL column convert to decimal and fix whitespaces

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a database which needs fixing, there is a column named FullPrice (nvarcharMAX). Changing data type to decimal is giving following error

> arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

And when I try to change the properties in Design (SSMS) then I get a timeout error.

I tried to remove all whitespaces and any other special characters.

```
<Current column>  <Desired column>
  FullPrice         FullPrice
    31270           312.70   
    34040           340.40
    41130           411.30
    64 98           64.98
    68 98           68.98
    69 98           69.98
    72 97           72.97
```

Remove whitespaces

```
UPDATE Table1
SET FullPrice = REPLACE(FullPrice, ' ', '')
```

Convert column and check if NULL values

```
Select FullPrice AS FullPrice_s, CASE WHEN Isnumeric(FullPrice) = 1
THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2),FullPrice) 
ELSE 0 END AS FullPrice
From Table1
```

If you check the screenshot the prices should be like this
1813.78
169.99
etc

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something, but your replace command is removing commas, not whitespace.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (CONVERT is a product specific function.)

Comment: Sorry yes, I will change that, but I also removed commas and whitespaces.

Comment: Using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Check if any values are still not numeric. Run SELECT query to return any records where FullPrice is not numeric. If there are any, figure out why and fix them. If there aren't, something else is issue.

Comment: What do you mean by `1813,78`? Is that two values or are using a comma instead of a decimal point?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: You can use TRY_CONVERT to identify the offending values, after which you can determine how to fix them.  See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7bpORTcb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the spaces, you can use the `STUFF()` to inject a decimal point into the proper position before converting to `NUMERIC`.

To inject the decimal point relative to the end of the string, calculate the inject position as an offset from `LEN(string)`. Alternately, the string can be reversed, the decimal point injected after the first two digits, and reversed again.

To guard against short values such as "9" representing "0.09", padding the input value with leading zeros may be needed.

```
SELECT *
FROM InputData I
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(I.FullPrice, ' ', '') AS NoSpaces) NS
CROSS APPLY (SELECT '00' + NS.NoSpaces AS Padded) P
CROSS APPLY (SELECT STUFF(P.Padded, LEN(P.Padded) - 1, 0, '.') AS Decimal) D
--CROSS APPLY (SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(P.Padded), 3, 0, '.')) AS Decimal) D
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), D.Decimal) AS Result) R
```

The above builds up the conversion step-by-step, using `CROSS APPLY`s to perform the calculations. For actual use, these calculations can be combined as follows. In this case, the reverse-stuff-reverse technique is used, because it eliminated the duplicate expression needed by the `LEN()` function.

```
SELECT
    *,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2),
        REVERSE(
            STUFF(
                REVERSE(
                    '000' + REPLACE(I.FullPrice, ' ', '')
                ),
            3, 0, '.')
        )
    ) AS Result
FROM InputData I
```

Results:

| FullPrice | NoSpaces | Padded | Decimal | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31270 | 31270 | 00031270 | 000312.70 | 312.70 |
| 34040 | 34040 | 00034040 | 000340.40 | 340.40 |
| 41130 | 41130 | 00041130 | 000411.30 | 411.30 |
| 64 98 | 6498 | 0006498 | 00064.98 | 64.98 |
| 68 98 | 6898 | 0006898 | 00068.98 | 68.98 |
| 69 98 | 6998 | 0006998 | 00069.98 | 69.98 |
| 72 97 | 7297 | 0007297 | 00072.97 | 72.97 |
| 99 | 99 | 00099 | 000.99 | 0.99 |
| 9 | 9 | 0009 | 00.09 | 0.09 |
|  |  | 000 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CR1-1HFE).

A more simplistic approach would be to convert to a larger type like  `DECIMAL(8,2)` and divide the converted result by 100.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @sampleData as table
(FullPrice  nvarchar(max))

insert into @sampleData(FullPrice)
values('1819 55')

insert into @sampleData(FullPrice)
values('1875 123')

UPDATE @sampleData
SET FullPrice = REPLACE(FullPrice, ' ', '')

Select FullPrice AS FullPrice_s, CASE WHEN Isnumeric(FullPrice) = 1
THEN convert(decimal(18,2),FullPrice)
ELSE 0 END AS FullPrice
From @sampleData

Select FullPrice AS FullPrice_s, CASE WHEN Isnumeric(FullPrice) = 1
THEN convert(decimal(6,2),FullPrice)
ELSE 0 END AS FullPrice
From @sampleData
```

Actual issue is `convert(decimal(6,2),FullPrice)`, the reason is the number of digits is more than 6 that's the reason you are getting Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric error.

Comment: After executing above code I get 239753.00 but I need 2397.53

Comment: try this query

Select FullPrice AS FullPrice_s, CASE WHEN Isnumeric(FullPrice) = 1
THEN convert(decimal(18,2),FullPrice)/100
ELSE 0 END AS FullPrice
From @sampleData

Answer (score -1):

My steps would be following:

1. Create a new temporary column `TempFullPrice`for the target datatype (Decimal(18,2))
2. Populate this temporary column with values from `FullPrice`, after performing some convert operations
3. Copy back the data from `TempFullPrice` to `FullPrice`
4. Update the datatype of `FullPrice` to `Decimal(18,2)`
5. Drop the temporary column

Queries:

`Alter table Table1 add TempFullPrice decimal(18,2)`

`update Table1 set TempFullPrice= convert(decimal(18,2) ,replace(FullPrice,' ',''))/100`

`update Table1 set FullPrice=TempFullPrice`

`alter table Table1 alter column FullPrice decimal(18,2)`

`alter table Table1 drop column TempFullPrice`